# Command not executed when attempting quick build - TexMaker

Tags: pdf, texmaker, ubuntu

I am new to writing LaTex documents and I am trying to compile my first one. However, the command for Quickbuild won't work and produces the following error:

```
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

The output format of the QuickBuild is set to PDF and I am using TexMaker for Ubuntu 18.04. How can I solve this issue ?

File is:

```
\begin{abstract}
This is a test document.
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: You may show us your input file.

Comment: the usual reason for getting that error is that you have installed an editor but not installed tex or it is not installed where the edito expects. Have you installed miktex or texlive?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Could+not+start+the+command.+pdflatex+